# Identity 2.0 Linking Multiple Login Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, asp.net-identity

I have finally managed to implement Facebook as an external login provider on my MVC website which seems to be working fine, but I am wondering what is the correct / secure way to allow multiple external login provides to be linked to a single account.

Lets say I login with my facebook ID, no existing account is found with the same email address and my website persists a new account with their email address and their facebook token etc associated.

Next day I login with my Google account, If i check my database for an account which already has a matching email address what should I do?

1) Link this Google account with the existing account automatically and
    log them in?

2) Ask the user if they wish to link their google account to the
    already existing account we found?

3) Something else?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really up to you. But the default provided in the VS2013 template assumes a one to many relationship between your internal user and any external logins. If you retrieve a user with UserManager, you will see a IList for each external provider the user has logged in with.

As they log in with the new provider, you would normally not automatically know the user is associated with another provider's login. When you login it looks up a user via external ProviderKey, so initally would not find any relation to an internal user. At that point you could search users by name, email (with customized user store) and so on to link as needed.

Comment: Would there be any security issues in automatically linking an existing account if they had the same email address?

Comment: Yep, you would need more than email address and name to avoid becoming a hacker target. In the one I am working on now, it is a customer id and birthday as the additional factors

Answer (score 3):

Assuming primary emails registered on facebook and google for example, are verified by them (which they usually are) I don't see any issues on linking them together.

I think the main problem is linking internal account with email that was not verified to be from specific user. If i create an account with email of other user and that email is not verified, when the other user creates an account it associates the data of the first user together and that way both users are using the same account.

Can anyone identify and explain potential flaws for my first claim please?